# UIPickerview on textField click

Tags: uipickerview

I Have a textfield in a UItableview. The user clicks on the textfield and I want a UIpickerview to popup with data from NSArray. I tried to implement this but the app crashes.
Please find my code below.

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [policyarraycount objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [policyarraycount count];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pv didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    txtPolicy.text = (NSString *)[policyarraycount objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used it to for an app a few months ago:

Setting up an IBAction and then create the UIPickerview there:

```
UIPickerView *thingPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[UIPickerView setAnimationDelegate:self];
thingPicker.delegate = self;
thingPicker.dataSource = self;
[thingPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
textField.inputView = thingPicker;
```

And set the parameters of the picker:

(with the textFieldNumber You can set each pickerView to a different textField)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)windPicker {

return 1; //Here if textFieldBOOL == # can also be used but I only use 1 component.
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thingPicker numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (textFieldNumber == 0) {
    return [fromAnArray count];

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thingPicker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (textFieldNumber == 0){
    return [fromAnArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thingPicker didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {  
if (textFieldNumber == 0) {
[textField setText:(NSString *)[fromAnArray objectAtIndex:row]];
```